# lua-ul (and soulutf8) doesn't work in xltabular

Tags: tables, xltabular, soulutf

Neither `lua-ul` nor `soulutf8` works in a `xltabular` table. It doesn't matter which command is used (`\strikeThrough`/`\underLine` or `\st`/`ul`, depending on the package option). And that's not cool. It complains several times `./file.tex:87: Leader required. <recently read> }  l.87 \end{xltabular}`. `Leader required` seems to be crucial.

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\RequirePackage{etex}
\RequirePackage{hyphsubst}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{fixltx2e}
\PassOptionsToPackage{activate={true,nocompatibility},verbose=silent,%
                      expansion=true,protrusion=true,final}{microtype}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,french]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
% \usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul} %or long command without soul
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\nonfrenchspacing
\begin{xltabular}{1\linewidth}{lXX}
  Seite & Froschkönig & Kommentar \\\hline
  \endfirsthead
  Seite & Froschkönig & Kommentar \\\toprule
  \endhead
        & & Fortsetzung...
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
       1 & In den alten \ul{Zeiten}, wo das Wünschen noch geholfen
       hat, lebte ein König, dessen Töchter waren alle schön; aber die
       jüngste war so schön, \ul{daß die Sonne selber, die doch so}
       vieles gesehen hat, sich verwunderte, sooft sie ihr ins Gesicht
       schien. & Nahe bei dem Schlosse des Königs lag ein großer
       dunkler Wald, und in dem Walde unter einer alten Linde war ein
       Brunnen; wenn nun der Tag recht heiß war, so ging das
       Königskind hinaus in den Wald und setzte sich an den Rand des
       kühlen Brunnens - und wenn sie \st{Langeweile} hatte, so nahm
       sie eine goldene Kugel, warf sie in die Höhe und fing sie
       wieder; und das war ihr liebstes Spielwerk. \\
       1 & Nun trug es sich einmal zu, \ul{daß die goldene Kugel der
         Königstochter} nicht in ihr Händchen fiel, das sie in die
       Höhe gehalten hatte, sondern vorbei auf die Erde schlug und
       geradezu ins Wasser hineinrollte. Die Königstochter folgte ihr
       mit den Augen nach,  aber die Kugel verschwand, und der Brunnen
       war tief, so tief, daß man keinen Grund sah. &  Da fing sie an
       zu weinen und weinte immer lauter und konnte sich gar nicht
       trösten. Und wie sie so klagte, rief ihr jemand zu: "`Was hast
       du vor, Königstochter, du schreist ja, daß sich ein Stein
       erbarmen möchte."' \\
       2--3 & Sie sah sich um, woher die Stimme käme, da erblickte sie
       einen Frosch, der seinen dicken, häßlichen Kopf aus dem Wasser
       streckte. "`Ach, du bist's, alter Wasserpatscher,"' sagte sie,
       "`ich weine über meine goldene Kugel, die mir in den Brunnen
       hinabgefallen ist."'& "`Sei still und weine nicht,"' antwortete
       der Frosch, "`ich kann wohl Rat schaffen, aber was gibst du
       mir, wenn ich dein Spielwerk wieder heraufhole?"' - "`Was du haben willst, lieber
                      Frosch,"' sagte sie; "`meine Kleider, meine
                      Perlen und Edelsteine, auch noch die goldene
                      Krone, die ich trage."' Der Frosch antwortete:
                      "`Deine Kleider, deine Perlen und Edelsteine und
                      deine \ul{goldene Krone}, die mag ich nicht: aber
                      wenn du mich liebhaben willst, und ich soll dein
                      Geselle und Spielkamerad sein, an deinem
                      Tischlein neben dir sitzen, von deinem goldenen
                      Tellerlein essen, aus deinem Becherlein trinken,
                      in deinem\st{ Bettlein schlafen: wenn du mir
                      }das versprichst, so will ich hinuntersteigen
                      und dir die goldene Kugel wieder heraufholen."'
                      \\
     3 & "`Ach ja,"' sagte sie, "`ich verspreche dir alles, was du
     willst, wenn du mir nur die Kugel wieder bringst."' Sie dachte
     aber: Was der einfältige Frosch schwätzt! Der sitzt im Wasser bei
     seinesgleichen und quakt und kann keines Menschen Geselle
     sein. Der Frosch, als er die Zusage erhalten hatte, tauchte
     seinen Kopf unter, sank hinab, und über ein Weilchen kam er
     wieder heraufgerudert, hatte die Kugel im Maul und warf sie ins
     Gras. & Die Königstochter war voll Freude, als sie ihr schönes
     Spielwerk wieder erblickte, hob es auf und sprang damit
     fort. "`Warte, warte,"' rief der Frosch, "`nimm mich mit, ich
     kann nicht so laufen wie du!"' Aber was half es ihm, daß er ihr
     sein Quak, Quak so laut nachschrie, als er konnte! Sie hörte
     nicht darauf, eilte nach Hause und hatte bald den armen Frosch
     vergessen, der wieder in seinen Brunnen hinabsteigen mußte.
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the reason for all those `\RequirePackage` before `\documentclass`? I see none. The purpose of `luatextra` used to be loading some packages deemed necessary for using LaTeX; among them is `fixltx2e`, which has been obsolete for a few years. Leave `luatextra` alone. There is no reason for loading `etex` on a TeX system less than five years old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Edit

With todays update of lua-ul the work-around is no longer needed.

### Old Answer

babel adds a command inside the tabular cell to \everyhbox and this breaks the leader command from lua-ul. You can reset it locally, but should report it to lua-ul:

Don't use the etex and the luatextra package. They are rather outdated.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,french]{babel}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul} %or long command without soul
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ul[1]{{\everyhbox{}\@underLine#1}}
\renewcommand\st[1]{{\everyhbox{}\@strikeThrough#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{6cm}}
a &In den alten \ul{Zeiten}, wo \st{Langeweile}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```